# Entity Framework incorrect seed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, csvhelper

I have 2 simple model classes:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}

public class SubCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

And a simple context:

```
public class SeederContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to seed the following csv files

**BetCategories.csv**:

```
Id,Description
1,Sports
2,Politics
```

**BetSubCategories**:

```
Id,Category_Id,Description
1,1,Soccer
2,1,Basketball
3,1,Tennis
4,1,Poker
5,2,Election
```

I built a seeder using `CsvHelper`:

```
public void Seed(SeederContext context)
{
    SeedTable<Category>("../../Data/BetCategories.csv", t =>
    {
        context.Categories.AddOrUpdate(c => c.Id, t);
        context.SaveChanges();
    });

    SeedTable<SubCategory>("../../Data/BetSubCategories.csv", t =>
    {
        context.SubCategories.AddOrUpdate(c => new { c.Description}, t);
        context.SaveChanges();
    });
}

public void SeedTable<T>(string path, Action<T[]> callback)
{
    var filename = path;

    if (filename != null)
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader);
            csvReader.Configuration.WillThrowOnMissingField = false;
            var list = csvReader.GetRecords<T>().ToArray();
            callback(list);
        }
}
```

The problem occurs when seeding the sub categories.

On the first seed (Categories) it goes OK and 2 categories written to the database.

On the second seed, the `SubCategories` goes OK and 5 sub categories are written to the database. BUT, they are also written to the `Categories` table - so now I have 2+5=7 categories in total.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is a very simple code-first with no configuration at all.

Please advise.

### Small update

when doing the seed manually - it works

```
SeedTable<Category>("../../Data/BetCategories.csv", t =>
{
    context.Categories.AddOrUpdate(c => c.Id, t);
    context.SaveChanges();
});

var subCategory = new SubCategory
{
    Category = context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Description == "Sports"),
    Description = "Soccer"
};

context.SubCategories.AddOrUpdate(c => c.Description, subCategory);
context.SaveChanges();

subCategory = new SubCategory
{
    Category = context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Description == "Sports"),
    Description = "Basketball"
};

context.SubCategories.AddOrUpdate(c => c.Description, subCategory);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: merge.
that's why I use AddOrUpdate

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this will solve

```
public class SubCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```